# Spring: DI of Spring Batch beans does not work

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-batch

I want to inject a bean from one context to my controller bean in MVC context. Here is my bean definition from MVC context:

```xml
<import resource="another.context.xml"/>

<bean name="myController" class="com.test.spring.web.Controller">
    <property name="batchJobRepository" ref="batchJobRepository"/>
</bean>
```

In the another context I defined a Spring Batch Job repository:

```xml
<bean id="batchJobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean>
```

My controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    private MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean batchJobRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/batch/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String batch() {
            Set<JobExecution> jes = batchJobRepository
                .getJobExecutionDao()
                .findRunningJobExecutions("firstJob");

            for (JobExecution je : jes) {
                System.out.println(je.isRunning());
            }
            return "Done!";
    }
```

The problem is a tricky one. I got an error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'myController' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/controllers.xml]: 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: 
Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25 implementing org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean' for property 'batchJobRepository'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25 implementing org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean] for property 'batchJobRepository': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

How can I fix it?

*UPD*

Added controller details.

*UPD2*

I tried to use

```
<aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

in `batchJobRepository` bean. But result is the same: `Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17 implementing org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository`

Comment: Can you post all class controller?

Comment: Sure. See my update.

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you have both a `@Controller` annotation and a corresponding `<bean>` declaration for your controller class? Also, why are you trying to inject a `FactoryBean` bean instead of the actual object that the factory creates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is caused because you are using the `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` incorrectly. This bean is actually a factory bean, that will return instances of `JobRepository`.

Your stacktrace is essentially saying that it can't cast a bean of type `JobRepository` to `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` and set the property in the controller. It should also be noted that `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` is a purely in-memory implementation, and will not connect to your database to manage job state.

Change your controller code to the following:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    private JobRepository batchJobRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/batch/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String batch() {
        Set<JobExecution> jes = batchJobRepository
            .getJobExecutionDao()
            .findRunningJobExecutions("firstJob");
        for (JobExecution je : jes) {
            System.out.println(je.isRunning());
        }
        return "Done!";
    }
}
```

A more elegant solution would be to declare a `JobExplorer` bean as follows:

```xml
<bean id="jobExplorer" 
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="myController" class="com.test.spring.web.Controller">
    <property name="jobExplorer" ref="jobExplorer"/>
</bean>
```

and then use the `JobExplorer` bean in your controller like so:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    @RequestMapping("/batch/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String batch() {
        Set<JobExecution> jes = jobExplorer
            .findRunningJobExecutions("firstJob");
        for (JobExecution je : jes) {
            System.out.println(je.isRunning());
        }
        return "Done!";
    }
}
```

I don't know why you thought that setting your aop config to use Aspect-J would help, but it won't and you shouldn't be using load time weaving if you don't need it.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the anotation `@Autowired` on your DI.

```
@Autowired
    private MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean batchJobRepository;
```

also add the folowing line on your spring context:

```
<!--AUTOWIRED-->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.system.rest.app.controller" />
```

Comment: This won't fix the problem itself. OP will still get the same stacktrace if they use autowiring.